# Browserify using different versions of the same module

Tags: mocha.js, browserify

Using browserify-node to bundle vendor modules.  One of these Fluxy has a dependency to Bluebird but an older version 1.2.4 while I would like to use a later version in my code.  The Fluxy dependency using Bluebird does a normal **require** module call.

If I do not bundle Blueprint (i.e. no usage from my code) then Bluebird is pulled from the **node_modules** directory in Fluxy npm installation.  However, if I bundle Bluebird (say from the 2.0 line) with a **require** module call the Fluxy dependency get's that version (not 1.2.4).

Only could come up with doing:

```
 b.require(
   './node_modules/bluebird/js/main/bluebird.js',
   {expose: 'mybluebird'}
 );
```

then using **mybluebird** in require module calls from my code.  However, this breaks my unit testing since require is looking for **mybluebird** which of course doesn't exist locally in the root **node_modules** directory.

Can different versions of the same module be handled in the client via Browserify with a different approach that is test friendly or can I modify Mocha to help me?